# Mudar logo no TCPDF através do form

Tags: php, tcpdf

Criei um gerador de PDF com o `TCPDF`, esta funcionando ok, so estou com um pequeno problema.
Eu quero que a `logo-marca` que entre, seja a que eu escolha no formulário.

Segue os códigos.

Código do fórmulario que envia os dados (`index.php`)

```
<table align="right" width="100%">
    <tr> 
        <td size="50px">Logo
            <div style="padding-top:5px;">
                <input name="logo" type="radio" 
                       value="http://www.example.com/logo1.jpg" /> LOGO 1
                <input name="logo" type="radio" 
                       value="http://www.example.com/logo2.jpg" /> LOGO 2
                <input name="logo" type="radio" 
                       value="http://www.example.com/logo3.jpg" /> LOGO 3
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Código `php` do arquivo que gera o `pdf` (`invoice2.php`)

```
<?
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header() {
        $image_file = 'http://www.example.com/logo.jpg';
      //$pdf->Image('images/image_demo.jpg', $x, $y, $w, $h, 'JPG', '',
      //     '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, $fitbox, false, false);
        $this->Image($image_file,'',8,80,'', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300,
                     'L', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    }
    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    }
}
```

Quero que por exemplo:
A pessoa que selecione a `LOGO 1`, ao gerar o `PDF`, a imagem que foi selecionada apareça no topo do `PDF` gerado.
No momento, a imagem que esta aparecendo é a que ta no código do `invoice2.php`.

```
public function Header() {
    $image_file = 'http://www.example.com/logo.jpg';
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando os métodos `GET` ou `POST` ao submeter o formulário.(No exemplo abaixo eu utilizei o `POST`)

A primeira coisa que fiz para ilustrar foi alterar o código `HTML`, adicionando o formulário, veja:

```
<form method="post" action="seu_script_que_gera_o_pdf.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align="right" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td size="50px">Logo
                <div style="padding-top:5px;">
                    <input name="logo" type="radio" 
                           value="http://www.example.com/logo1.jpg" /> LOGO 1
                    <input name="logo" type="radio" 
                           value="http://www.example.com/logo2.jpg" /> LOGO 2
                    <input name="logo" type="radio" 
                           value="http://www.example.com/logo3.jpg" /> LOGO 3
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Agora podemos alterar o `script` que gera o `PDF` para se comportar de acordo veja:

```
<?
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {
    public function Header($logo) {
        $image_file = $logo; //'http://www.example.com/logo.jpg';
      //$pdf->Image('images/image_demo.jpg', $x, $y, $w, $h, 'JPG', '', 
                    '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, $fitbox, false, false);
        $this->Image($image_file,'',8,80,'', 'JPG', '', 'T', false, 300, 
                     'L', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    }
    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
    }
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $image = $_POST['logo'];
  
    $myPdf = new MYPDF();
    $myPdf->Header($logo);
}
```

O método `Header` foi alterado para que seja possível informar qual a imagem desejada quando o formulário for submetido.

Comment: 1º: Strict Standards: Declaration of MYPDF::Header() should be compatible with TCPDF::Header() in /invoice2.php on line 12

 2º: Warning: Missing argument 1 for MYPDF::Header(), called in /home/evolucao/public_html/celg2/tcpdf.php on line 3537 and defined in /invoice2.php on line 13

 3º: TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image:

Comment: você pode optar por alterar o método construtor para remover o strict standards. Veja o código que alterei no pastebin http://pastebin.com/r16EPGMV